getProgramAccounts return always empty
i'm trying to use GetProgramAccounts in python to recover data pool but my programm always return empty.
At the begenning I had tried to use filer , but as it didn't work , I took the decision to use it without filter in order to analyse the result of the function.
But it's the same without filter.
I'm using quicknode free.
Below is the part relevant of my code.
Fonction pour récupérer les comptes de programme de marché
async def fetch_market_accounts(connection: AsyncClient, market_program_id: Pubkey, commitment: str = "finalized"):
try:
response = await connection.get_program_accounts(
market_program_id,
commitment=commitment,
encoding="base64"
)
return response
except Exception as e:
logger.error(f"Erreur lors de la récupération des comptes du programme : {str(e)}")
return None
Fonction pour formater les clés du pool de liquidité
async def get_pool_keys(connection: AsyncClient, base: Pubkey, quote: Pubkey, commitment: str = "finalized"):
market_program_id = Pubkey.from_string("675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8")
accounts_response = await fetch_market_accounts(connection, market_program_id, commitment)
if not accounts_response or not accounts_response.value:
print("No accounts found")
return "FAIL"
Someone could help me? Thank in advance
